# Check if autofac module is already registered?

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac

In our (huge, rather unmanageable) configuration there are many modules.

One of them is vital for another module to function as expected, but may also be problematic to register twice (I know, this is the real problem...).

There's [conditional registration of instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18988210/conditional-component-registration-in-autofac) but none of these solutions seem to be relevant for a whole module.

As mentioned in the comments, this behavior is by design.

My question is: How would I (best) make my module registrations singletons?

One way would be using a guard flag

- Register a uniquely named instance of something (doesn't matter what)
- Check if already registered on module load entry
- Skip to end if already registered - otherwise register the uniquely named instance

Comment: https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/1292#issuecomment-949655828

Comment: I understand that it's working as designed. I am looking for a way to get it to work the way I would prefer.